# Ionic3 lazy loaded modules entry components

Tags: ionic2

In my Ionic app I have a page called "MyCustomer". MyCustomer page has the following IonicPage Config:

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'MyCustomer',
})
```

From MyCustomer page I will be opening a component called "CustomerEdit" in modal. So I have defined the CustomerEdit component in MyCustomer Page module file in both declarations and entry components and below is the @NgModule code for Page

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MyCustomerPage } from './my-customer.page';
import { CustomerEdit } from '../../components/CustomerEdit/CustomerEdit';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     MyCustomerPage,CustomerEdit 
  ],
  imports: [
     CommonModule,IonicPageModule,
     IonicPageModule.forChild(MyCustomerPage),
 ],
  entryComponents:[CustomerEdit]
})
export class MyCustomerPageModule {}
```

When I try to open the CustomerEdit component in modal like this

```
  Open(){
     let modal=this.modalCtrl.create(CustomerEdit);
     modal.present();
  }
```

I get the following error.

```
No component factory found for CustomerEdit. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Only pages could be used to create a modal... You'd need to create another page with that component inside, and then create the modal using that page.

Comment: Thank you...But i didn't any documentation regarding this,can you share a link about this so that i can learn little bit more about this

Comment: Np, glad to help :) Yes, you could take a look at the **[modal docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/)**